# How to cache images that changes frequently in PHP?

Tags: php, image, caching, browser-cache

I want to know if there is a way to cache or store images which changes frequently in websites? For example; in your website, a user uploaded 10 images and select a cover image.But the user (or users) can delete their images or change their cover images etc. at any time.

I know I can cache databse queries if I fetch image names from database, but loading these images sometimes takes much time. There is nothing to do with  browser caching, I think.

Is there any way to reduce the loading of site with images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers cache images my theirs names. If client opens file `abc.jpg`, next time this images will be from cache (if cache is enabled). So if you upload file on server, set correct name to it. Or you can disable cache hardly using `abc.jpg?1`